# jQuery- own code conflicts with Revolution Slider

Tags: jquery, debugging, revolution-slider, conflicting-libraries

I have written my own little jquery code for a hover effect, it worked perfectly. But when i added the revolution slider to the page the hover effect stopt working corectly.
When you hover the socialmedia buttons you see a black background just before the triangles slide in, this black background didn't apear there before.

This is my code:

```
    <div class="effect">
        <svg class="facebook-svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 30 30" enable-background="new 0 0 30 30" xml:space="preserve">
            <path fill="#000000" d="M17.252,11.106V8.65c0-0.922,0.611-1.138,1.041-1.138h2.643V3.459l-3.639-0.015c-4.041,0-4.961,3.023-.961,4.961v2.701H10v4.178h2.336v11.823h4.916V15.284h3.316l0.428-4.178H17.252z"/>
        </svg>
        <div class="mask first"></div>
        <div class="mask second"></div>
    </div>
```

---

```
$( ".effect" ).hover(
            function() {

                $(".first", this).finish();
                $(".second", this).finish();

                if ( $( "img", this).length ) {
                    $width  = $('img', this).width() + 'px';
                    $height = $('img', this).height() + 'px';
                }
                if ( $( "svg", this).length ) {
                    $width  = $('svg', this).width() + 'px';
                    $height = $('svg', this).height() + 'px';
                }

                $( ".first", this ).css({"left" : $width, "top" : $height});
                $( ".second", this ).css({"left" : "-" + $width, "top" : "-" + $height});


                $( ".first", this ).css({"opacity" : "1"});
                $( ".second", this ).css({"opacity" : "1"});

                $( ".first", this ).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
                                top: "-0",
                                left: "-0"
                              }, 200, function() {
                                // Animation complete.
                              });
                $( ".second", this ).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
                                top: "+0",
                                left: "+0"
                              }, 200, function() {
                                // Animation complete.
                              });
              },
            function() {            
                $( ".first", this ).animate({
                                top: "+" + $height,
                                left: "+" + $width
                              }, 200, function() {
                                $( ".first", this ).css({"opacity" : "0"});
                              });
                $( ".second", this ).animate({
                                top: "-" + $height,
                                left: "-" + $width
                              }, 200, function() {
                                $( ".second", this ).css({"opacity" : "0"});
                              });

            $width = undefined;
            $height = undefined;
        });
```

I have tried fixing it with `no.conflict()` but with no luck so far.
When i put the Revolution Slider to Debug mode it works correctly wich i find strange.

Here is the [website](http://patrick.pixel2code.nl/)
The socialmedia buttons are located in the footer.

Thank you in advance to anyone that takes the time to look at this.

Comment: I've opened the website, and I can't see what you describe. Please, follow this guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to edit your question

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the day after i posted this i checked my site again and the bug magically disappeared!? I didn't do a thing to the code. But atleast its fixed! :)

Comment: Glad to know it. Perhaps next time refreshing the browser cache with Ctrl+F5 will help you. Now it's your turn to delete the question, please.